# How to remove focus from text field when user presses ESC angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to remove focus from input text field from user with the ESC key press. I don't know how to do it with text input fields. Below code works perfectly to detect the ESC key is pressed.

```
// Triggered Listener to detect event raised from DOM.
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: 
KeyboardEvent) {
 if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Anyone can help how to do??
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call the `blur` method of the input field in the handler of the `keydown.escape` event:

```
<input #txtInput (keydown.escape)="txtInput.blur()">
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g1sjj9) for a demo.